# C# - How to implement DateTime.TryParse for 24 hour time format

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone demonstrate how you could implement DateTime.TryParse into my current code which takes in intergers. For example a 24 hour time format 23:00

```
private void textBox2_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int numberEntered;

    if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out numberEntered))
    {
         if (numberEntered < 1 || numberEntered > 28)
         {
              MessageBox.Show("");
              textBox2.Text = 5.ToString();
         }
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("");
         textBox2.Text = 5.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a DateTime object with hour and minutes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
    void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dateEntered;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateEntered))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dateEntered.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to enter valid 24hr time");
        }

    }
```

I would recommend doing some reading up on the various parameters available for [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx), and choosing the ones that match your situation with care. Also have a look at the values of actual DataTime objects that get generated by this parse, since they will have a Date part as well - if you use this data later on (particularly for comparing these times) these details could prove important.

Answer (score 3):

```
string strDate = "23:00";
string format = "HH:mm";
DateTime res;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out res);
```

Answer (score 1):

hi guys am posting for first time.. it works for me..

```
DateTime dtSurgStartTime;
bool blnStart = DateTime.TryParseExact(txtSURGERY_START_DATE_TIME.Text, @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null,
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtSurgStartTime);
```